# C# Instance Class with Static Methods - using methods differently between threads

Tags: c#, hook

Hello I have this code here:

```
Memory.OpenProcess(Processes[0].Id);
Hook.Apply(........);
```

Memory and Hook are both non-static classes, and openprocess and Apply are both static methods within those classes.

However, the problem is, for each instance of my Memory or Hook, I want to have a different process opened, and a different Hook applied.

What I want to do is:

```
Memory newMemory = new Memory();
newMemory.OpenProcess(processes[1].Id);

Hook newHook = new Hook();
newHook.Apply(....);
```

But of course I cannot do this because the methods are static and not particular to each instance.

I cannot change the static methods because these methods are coming from a dll in which I do not have access to the source code.

Any ideas?

**Edit: I want to do this so I can avoid having to rehook the process every time a new thread comes along that is working with a different process.

Comment: What happens if you call twice OpenProcess with different ids? Will both processes be opened? Or first would close?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot do that by design. The implementor of the classes from the dll you are consuming might have explicitly want to avoid the functionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There could be a piece of truth in it, but also it could happen, that implementor was lazy or didn't think about his consumers)))

Comment: I would like to keep a positive thinking related to this and believe it was an architectural decision :)

Comment: I wish I had your belief in people. So many "Open API" are developed by people, who don't care about customers. Met at least 3 big Russian companies with such developers. So had to reinvent wheels, create "dirty-hacks" and so on... Lucky you, really)

Answer (score 1):

You can load each thread in different [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx), that would give you different static methods.

Also, [ThreadStaticAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) might be helpful for you. Don't sure if it fits you, but give it a look.

Upd: More info about using AppDomains. Lets assume, that you have 3-rd party class `Memory` defined as follows. (And you cannot change it, and it uses inner static variables)

```
// Cannot be changed
public class Memory
{
    static int StaticId;

    public static void OpenProcess(int id)
    {
        StaticId = id;
    }

    public static int GetOpenedId()
    {
        return StaticId;
    }
}
```

You can write a wrapper, deriving from [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) (that's important):

```
class MemoryWrap : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void OpenProcess(int id)
    {
        Memory.OpenProcess(id);
    }

    public int GetOpenedId()
    {
        return Memory.GetOpenedId();
    }
}
```

So if you create instances of `MemoryWrap` not by `new` keyword, but using `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` in another domain, each instance would have it's own static contexts. Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type = typeof(MemoryWrap);

        var domain1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain 1");
        var memory1 = (MemoryWrap)domain1.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);

        var domain2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain 2");
        var memory2 = (MemoryWrap)domain2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);

        memory1.OpenProcess(1);
        memory2.OpenProcess(2);

        Console.WriteLine(memory1.GetOpenedId());
        Console.WriteLine(memory2.GetOpenedId());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It would print:

```
1
2
```

PS: in that example I didn't do the clean up just for readability (unloading domains with `AppDomain.Unload()` and other things). Don't forget to do it in you code. + There is some mess with lifetime of objects in another domain, but it is next level of problems)))

Comment: threadstaticattribute is not useful because I can't touch the class itself since it is buried in a DLL i don't have the source for :(

Comment: If dll is .Net managed library, Did you tried to get code using Reflector?

Comment: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/ allows you to see source of managed libraries (which were not obfustrated or else-how protected) But be sure, that you don't break someone's copyright, OK?)

Comment: I tried reflector.. result? "This item is obfuscated and can not be translated.
"

Comment: Someone didn't want you to see it's source( No luck here. But idea with different AppDomains is still alive.

Comment: different app domains would mean that I have to perform code to bridge app domain every time I use the hook to get something? doesn't that have a large resource cost?

Comment: What about solution, made by Armen Shimoon (below). Did you tried it?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work because Hook.Apply and the other methods all rely on an internally stored (static) memory value of where the hook is. Sure, i can apply the hook to another process, but the problem is that all subsequent actions using the dll refer to that process, and to get back to the other process I need to rehook. (do you see what I mean?)  -- the process ID, the window handle, the hook.. all of it is static

Comment: @Jason Sorry, but have to leave you with this um.. mess. 6 o'clock in the morning - it's time to sleep)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I will try to answer anyways.

You could define two new classes:

```
public class MemoryInstance : Memory
{
  private var m_instanceProcessId;

  public MemoryInstance(var processId) : base()
  {
    m_instanceProcessId = processId;
  }

  public void OpenProcess()
  {
    Memory.OpenProcess(m_instanceProcessId);
  }
}

public class HookInstance: Hook
{
  private var m_hookId;

  public HookInstance(var hookId) : base()
  {
    m_hookId = hookId;
  }

  public void Apply()
  {
    Hook.Apply(m_hookId);
  }
}
```

Then in your code you could call:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
  MemoryInstance newMemory = new MemoryInstance(processes[1].Id);
  HookInstance newHook = new HookInstance(hookId);

  newMemory.OpenProcess();
  newHook.Apply();
}
```

Comment: oh yes.. this won't work because after the process is hooked, the only way I can reference that hook is through a direct-to-class Hook.doSomeAction ... so I need to make an instance of the hook otherwise I can only hook one thing at a time. Do you see what i mean? For example.. Hook.Apply ... whenever i use that apply method, it will always be static and thus uses whatever process I happen to have hooked last (because all the methods are static)

Answer (score 0):

See , if the API writers are doing that it must be for some  reason , you should consult your API writers for he reason or if they can provide you something at instamnce level.

BUT for circumvent your situation , you can use the method provided The_Smallest above.

or you can make use of Reflection as shown below

```
Memory m = Activator.CreateInstance("Your Dll Name", true) , here true stands for the calling of private constructor.
```

But i am not convinced , you should do it , you first call to the API writer to get the reason of  doing this.